# Spring junit configuration

Tags: java, spring, testing, junit

I have tried many configurations. I try to invoke simple System.out as a test to check my configuration :

```
public class DaoTest {
@Test
public void commentTest() {
    System.out.println("test working");
}}
```

My configuration classes use properties file to get the values and class that holds string constants values:

```
 public static final String DATASOURCE_PATH = "dataSource.driver_class_name";
```

I annotated the test class with:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@PropertySource(
        value={"classpath:spring.properties"},
        ignoreResourceNotFound = true)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = { TestConfig.class, ConfigurationConstants.class, ApplicationConfigCore.class, HibernateConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration()
@ActiveProfiles(profiles = "test")
```

Where's TestConfig basically consists of classpath because I tried different ways yet still don't know where's my mistake.
Also i added the spring.properties file both to the resources file of main as well as test package.

So the question I have is where's mistake and when we deploy web app in spring it takes resources from `src/main/resources` folder, so what's the case with tests. Is it gonna be: `src/test/resources`?
In case of tests that takes the configuration, like my case, from main app configuration classes - do those classes will find right `src/main/resources` folder or will they try to check for test/./properties file ?

BTW. when location of properties added to `@ContextConfiguration` i got
`Cannot process locations AND classes for context configuration` exception

Comment: Is it spring or spring-boot project? What is the error you get?

Comment: It's spring mvc project. I got `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext` followed by `Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Content is not allowed in prolog.` It seems Junit expects XML file instead of properties file to get configuration for Spring

Comment: Did you try to simplify your test configuration? For instance having `@ActiveProfiles` annotation in your test you don't need `@PropertySource`. By passing "test" as a value for `@ActiveProfiles` spring will be looking for file with name `application-test.properties`. I'd recommend you to leave minimal config, make sure it works and try adding other annotations one by one. It would also be helpful if you update the question with full stacktarce

Comment: After trial and error approach I came to certain conclusions: My configuration takes data from properties and somehow JUNIT won't recognize this file from src/main/resources folder but test one. So after I changed the property file to xml like one with `entry -> key` values it sees it now. The second thing is Junit won't see Constants.class event though I put it in `@ContextConfiguration`. The error I'm getting now is that my resources are empty (yet still on test/resources). The problem didn't exist when all my configuration was hard coded.